# Hover behavior for a dt with multiple dds in CSS

Tags: css

I'm referring to this question:
[Hover behavior for a dl list in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591739/hover-behavior-for-a-dl-list-in-css/29591970#29591970)

The accepted answer will only highlight the first `<dd>` following a `<dt>`, but when there are multiple `<dd>`s only the first (adjacent) one is affected.

I've looked at the combinators: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp but none really cover multiple `<dd>`s since they are not actually descendant or child elements of the `<dt>`.

Is there a CSS solution that will affect all `<dd>`s following a `<dt>`?

Comment: Is the number of dd's the same after every dt?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it varies.

Comment: Is there a predictable limit to the number of dd's i.e. 5 or 6?

Comment: Probably 5 would cover it, but I'd prefer a solution than can account for an unknown number of `<dd>`s.

Comment: I have a solution that will work with 5, but will try for the more generic solution. Are the classes unique on the dd's following the dts. i.e. firstDD, secondDD, etc??

Comment: No, not unique in the way you mention.  Currently I either don't have any classes on them or the classes are related to text alignment and such, but not the order of the dd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point is

```
/* change color of dd siblings of the hovered dt */
dt:hover ~ dd { 
  color: white;
}

/* set color:initial for dd siblings of dt siblings of the hovered dt */
dt:hover ~ dt ~ dd { 
  color: initial;
}
```

Please look at this snippet (I've updated the referred answer):

```css
dl {
  overflow: hidden;
}

dt {
  height: 50em;
  margin-bottom: -48.8em;
  background: white;
}

dt:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
}


dd {
  pointer-events: none;
}

dt:hover ~ dd {
  color: white;
}

dt:hover ~ dt ~ dd {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Term 1</dt>
  <dd>1st Definition of term 1<br>&hellip;<br>&hellip;</dd>
  <dd>2nd Definition of term 1<br>&hellip;<br>&hellip;</dd>
  <dd>3rd Definition of term 1<br>&hellip;<br>&hellip;</dd>
  
  <dt>Term 2</dt>
  <dd>Definition of term 2<br>&hellip;</dd>
  
  <dt>Term3 </dt>
  <dd>Definition of term 3</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: While technically correct, code-only answers aren't quite as useful.  It would be nice if you would explain the [general sibling combinator](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using an nth-of-type selector to select the dd's in combination with the generic sibling selector.

```
dt:hover,
dt:hover ~ dd:nth-of-type(1),
dt:hover ~ dd:nth-of-type(2), 
dt:hover ~ dd:nth-of-type(3) {
    background:#ddd;
}
```